# PHP8.1 - Deprecated Errors for SolrObject/SolrDocument

Tags: php, deprecation-warning, php-8.1

Running php cli throws these deprecated errors even simple `php -v`. But [SolrObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.solrobject.php) is a standard php class so I'm not sure why it's complaining about itself and how to fix it?

> Deprecated: Return type of SolrObject::offsetExists($property_name)
> should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed
> $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be
> used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrObject::offsetGet($property_name)
> should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed
> $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be
> used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrObject::offsetSet($property_name,
> $property_value) should either be compatible with
> ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrObject::offsetUnset($property_name)
> should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed
> $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be
> used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrDocument::offsetExists($fieldName)
> should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed
> $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be
> used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrDocument::offsetGet($fieldName) should
> either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset):
> mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to
> temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrDocument::offsetSet($fieldName,
> $fieldValue) should either be compatible with
> ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrDocument::offsetUnset($fieldName)
> should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed
> $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be
> used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrDocument::current() should either be
> compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrDocument::next() should either be
> compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrDocument::key() should either be
> compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrDocument::valid() should either be
> compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Return type of SolrDocument::rewind() should either be
> compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: SolrDocument implements the Serializable interface, which
> is deprecated. Implement __serialize() and __unserialize() instead (or
> in addition, if support for old PHP versions is necessary) in Unknown
> on line 0
>
> Deprecated: SolrModifiableParams implements the Serializable
> interface, which is deprecated. Implement __serialize() and
> __unserialize() instead (or in addition, if support for old PHP versions is necessary) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: SolrQuery implements the Serializable interface, which is
> deprecated. Implement __serialize() and __unserialize() instead (or in
> addition, if support for old PHP versions is necessary) in Unknown on
> line 0
>
> Deprecated: SolrDisMaxQuery implements the Serializable interface,
> which is deprecated. Implement __serialize() and __unserialize()
> instead (or in addition, if support for old PHP versions is necessary)
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2022 00:35:54) (NTS) Copyright (c) The
> PHP Group Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.1.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
> with Xdebug v3.1.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans

Running Devilbox v1.10.0 (2022-01-28) / Docker

Comment: Solr is not a "standard" PHP class, it is a [PECL extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385351/231316). Looks like someone provided a patch that was recently [merged to add support for PHP 8.1](https://github.com/php/pecl-search_engine-solr/pull/30).

Comment: @ChrisHaas can it be disabled in php.ini like other PHP extensions?

Comment: The reverse is actually true. It can be manually _enabled_ in php.ini, it is not by default. Scan your directives, and especially being Docker, the derivatives, for something actually turning it on in the first place.